# Error Database Connection in CodeIgninter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Currently I'm developing a project using:

- PHP Framework CodeIgniter (V.2..)
- Database SQL Server 2018

As usual it runs well, but sometimes if I refresh it many times or there are about 10 users accessing it in real time, suddenly I get error although my database setting is correct. The error says:

[image]

I'm just curious, it's a framework issue; can't handle a huge database so the server disconnected it automatically, perhaps the query is not effective, or bad scripting....

Maybe anyone can share the experiences due to this issue or solution?

Comment: check concurrent user access count, and max_connection in your server

Comment: Numerous other possible issues depending on php version, SQL driver used ( no php SQL native drivers any more) etc

Comment: User access is granted (connected), max_connection = 10k